# How to set the application icon for a libGDX desktop application?

Tags: java, libgdx, lwjgl

I am trying to setup an application icon from the -desktop specific class with:

```
package org.osgameseed.games.animalflip;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Files;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "AnimalFlip";
        cfg.useGL20 = false;
        cfg.width = 800;
        cfg.height = 600;
        cfg.addIcon("data/ic_launcher.png", Files.FileType.Internal);

        new LwjglApplication(new AnimalFlipGame(), cfg);
    }
}
```

The icon is not set (at least on Linux), any idea on how to set it ?

Comment: Maybe your image doesn't get included when you export or not in the right location. How do you export?

Comment: Afaik you don't need to export the image, it is placed on the proper data path, the configuration loader will fail if I rename the file so I am sure it's being loaded.

Comment: That's not what I meant. For instance, if you export from eclipse as jar, your assets might not get exported as you have in your dir.

Comment: I am assembling the jar using ANT build rules, the icon is included. But again like I said, the configuration loader is able to find the file, so is not really a resource locating issue. I just can't figure how to instruct libGDX to use the icon for the window icon.

Comment: Open your exported jar and check if you have a data folder and inside that if you have your icon. Your jar won't crash if the icon is not there.

Comment: Please ignore the jar import/export part, I am running the explication directly from Android Studio, there is no jar generated, just the plain class path being used, the icon is not set.

Answer (score 17):

Take a look into the api (addIcon(...)):

> **Adds a window icon**. Icons are tried in the order added, the first one
>   that works is used. Typically three icons should be provided: 128x128
>   (for Mac), 32x32 (for Windows and Linux), and 16x16 (for Windows).

Maybe your icon has the wrong dimensions, so it won't get set. Else it should work!

**Just to mention you just set the small icon in the left upper edge (if the application is started) with it not the icon you would see at the desktop!**
[image: the small icon]

Comment: The icon does have the proper dimmensions: ic_launcher.png: PNG image data, 32 x 32, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced, however it does not show up.

Comment: Has anyone found the solution? It does not show up on my Mac too.

Comment: So how then do you set the desktop icon? This doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: @Jake use an installation wrapper to set the according icon while installation. The desktop icon is not a part of the app code but can be set while installation of an application. It is a part of windows/Linux folder/file Definition if I know that right.

Comment: 32x32 appears low-quality and pixelated. I switched to 128x128 and it seems to be working just fine. I'm on Linux if it matters

Answer (score 0):

that brought the Icon into my Mac-Dock! ;)
Be sure to call it in your Lwjgl-Thread

```
/**
 * workaround for Mac
 */
private static void setApplicationIcon() {
    try {
        Class<?> cls = Class.forName("com.apple.eawt.Application");
        Object application = cls.newInstance().getClass().getMethod("getApplication").invoke(null);

        FileHandle icon = Gdx.files.local("icons/icon.png");
        application.getClass().getMethod("setDockIconImage", java.awt.Image.class)
                .invoke(application, new ImageIcon(icon.file().getAbsolutePath()).getImage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // nobody cares!
    }
}
```